# Excel Pivot Table Chart - How NOT to plot any Top 5 items with a zero value OR only plot the first 5 regardless of value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have created a Pivot Table in Excel and used the Value Filters > Top 10 filter to only show the Top 5 entries based on a particular value.

I have created a Pivot Table Chart based on the above pivot table.

The pivot table and chart work fine so long as the top 5 values are above zero. That is, the pivot table only displays 5 rows of data and the chart only displays 5 bars. See examples below:

[image]

[image]

However, when multiple items have the same value and make it into the top 5, then ALL of those items are listed. For example, let's say the first value is 12, the second value is 6, the third value is 2 and all other values are the same, then I get a chart similar to this:

[image]

Now, by a happy coincidence in my case, the items with the same value always happen to be zero. So I assumed I could set the pivot table/chart to not display items of a zero value. However, nothing I have tried works.

So far I've tried:

- different settings for the "For empty cells show" in pivot table options
- setting a value filter on the value column to only display values above zero
- gone into Excel's Advanced options to ensure that the "Show a zero in cells that have zero value" is **not** selected

I assume part of the problem is that the values are based on a "Sum" calculation and not a direct cell entry.

Obviously, my approach with using the zero values to fix my issue is only workable because of the happy coincidence that exists with my data, but ideally what I want is to chart the Top 5 items and when there's more than 5 items because they share a value, to only chart the **first 5** and forget the rest.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: I would consider creating your charts from an area outside the pivot table. Let the pivot table decide all the possible data, then use formulas to reference the pivot table. Like L4 = E4 (E4 is part of the Pivot, and L4 is NOT part of the pivot). Then create your charts with data in L4:M8. Just an idea, but may require you to continually change the chart area if you want to chart top 5 vs top 8 vs top 10, etc. Another idea is creating a helper column in your data, one that ranks your data based on some criteria. Then you could bring that rank into your pivot filter.

Comment: Long time not using Excel, but I think to remember is that a typicall error is to assume that empty (blanks) cells are 0. try filtering categories with values cells having blanks. If that doesn't work, please add some sample data and share a bit about the context so we could think about the retrictions for workarounds (i.e. should not use auxiliary sheets)